# Redux ToolKit: Submit a dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hello i am trying to use redux toolkit, but i have doubts how can i send a dispatch to change the state of my reducer

My Store:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./rootReducer', () => {
    const newRootReducer = require('./rootReducer').default;
    store.replaceReducer(newRootReducer);
  });
}

export default store;
```

my root reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { togglePopUp } from '../slices/popupMenu';
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  togglePopUp: togglePopUp.reducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

my slice:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  popUpIsOpen: false,
};

const togglePopUp = createSlice({
  name: 'popUp',
  initialState: INITIAL_STATE,
  reducers: {
    toggle: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action);
    },
  },
});

export const { toggle } = togglePopUp.actions;
export { togglePopUp };
```

my jsx:

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { popUpIsOpen } = useSelector(RootState => RootState.togglePopUp);
            <p onClick={() => dispatch(toggle())}>
              My Account
              <span>
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                  className="adjust"
                  icon={faAngleDown}
                  size="xs"
                  fixedWidth
                  color="white"
                />
              </span>
            </p>
```

I'm basically trying to make a toggle menu when clicked change the status to false or true

where false: closed /
true: open,

I'm following the redux toolkiit tutorial, but I was unsure how to send my dispatch and how to change the status of my popup menu on my slice

Comment: do you have a Redux Provider that takes your store around your app?

Comment: Yes everything works normal I have my useSelector correctly the problem is that I don't know how to change my state in my Toggle const in my slice.

Comment: Basically my initial value is:

popUpIsOpen: false,

ie closed menu
and when I send the dispatch I want to change the value of this state

Answer (score 0):

i solve with this.

```
const togglePopUp = createSlice({
  name: 'popUp',
  initialState: INITIAL_STATE,
  reducers: {
    toggle: (state, action) => {
      state.popUpIsOpen: !state.popUpIsOpen
    },
  },
});
```